# Jquery make newly inserted div draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I have the following snippet:

```
var Bar = $('#' + this.container.attr('ID') + 'b' + barID);
var Marker = $("<div class='marker m" + styleID + "'>" + label + "</div>");
Bar.parent().append(Marker);
Marker.draggable(
    {
        axis: "x",
        grid: [this.GridSize, this.GridSize]
    }
);
```

This doesn't make the marker draggable as I want it to, is there any way to make it draggable without assigning it an ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give the `div` assigned to `Marker` a class of `marker mStyleId` so couldn't you just select it using one of those?

```
$(".m"+styleId).draggable();
```